# I am beginner in Junit and I am unable to test these method so could anyone help me out from this situation

Tags: junit

```
public String serialize(Map<String, Object> data) throws IOException {
    logger.debug("Starting serialisation of json response for thread id [{}] and string [{}]",
            Thread.currentThread().getId(), data);
    return (data == null) ? "{}" : new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data);
}
```

Comment: Create an input (a map). Call your method. Check that it returns the expected output. That's the simplest test you could write. Since you have a special case for a null input, add another test checking that you get the expected output when the input is null.

Comment: Actually I didn't get any idea what test method I have to use for this method

Comment: Then read this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

To test the method, one creates a reasonable input value, then invokes the method, then checks the output value. In your case, the input value is a `Map<String, Object>` and the output is some `String`. So to make this work, you would write something like this:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {

  // First, create the object you're testing
  MyObject aor = new MyObject();

  // Now create the Map you'll be providing to the method
  Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<>();

  // Put the right data value into the Map
  Object data = ???
  inputMap.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), data);

  // Invoke the method
  String result = aor.serialize(inputMap);

  // Now assert that the result you got is the result you expected
  assertEquals("this is what I expected to get", result);
}
```

And there you go.